# How to open a specific android app (skyfire browser) from within another app?

Tags: android

I am trying to open a given URL from within my android app, but I need that URL to open in the skyfire browser, not the default browser. This is because the pages I link to only work correctly in skyfire.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do this. Don't force the user to use a particular application. If they want to use a different default browser, that's their problem. It's YOUR problem to get the pages to display correctly in all browsers. What if they don't have skyfire installed? What you should do is inform the user that pages work best in skyfire and then continue.

Answer (score 2):

If Skyfire documents a particular `Intent` that will cause a page to open in their browser (and their browser alone), and you determine that the `Intent` will work (via `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`), use it.

Otherwise, see Falmarri's answer.